# Maven Fails to Resolve Avuncular Dependency

Tags: maven

I have a maven project setup like so:

```
.
├── pom.xml (1)
├── common
|   └── pom.xml (2)
└── experimental
    ├── pom.xml (3)
    └── data_viewer
        └── pom.xml (4)
```

`pom.xml` (1) looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>common</module>
  <module>experimental</module>
</modules>
```

`pom.xml` (2):

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>common</artifactId>
```

`pom.xml` (3):

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.company.experimental</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>data_viewer</module>
</modules>
```

`pom.xml` (4):

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.experimental</groupId>
    <version>1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>data_viewer</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Running `mvn package -pl data_viewer -am` from the `experimental` directory results in the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project data_viewer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.experimental:data_viewer:jar:1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.company:common:jar:1
```

Why does maven not know how to resolve `com.company.common`? Running `Apache Maven 3.2.5`

Comment: did you build the common jar? if you did, make sure it is in your local repo. I think "common" is never built becoz you run the build only for "experimental". try to run the build from your "parent".

Comment: I tried running `mvn install -pl common` from the parent directory prior to running `mvn package -pl data_viewer -am`, it still fails, also the `-am` flag should have maven build all dependencies for me I thought..

Comment: try to run from parent "mvn clean install".

Comment: First you should try to run `mvn clean package`  from the root. Second run the `mvn -pl commont clean package` from the root as well. Furthermore don't use `${project.parent.version}` better use `${project.version}` instead. BTW: Shows `mvn clean` from root the correct order which means building `common` before `data_viewer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor builds cannot compute and build modules specified by the parent of the current aggregator pom, i.e. they cannot traverse up.  But they can traverse down to any level and build modules of children.

So, in the above case, run the following from the root folder.

```
mvn package -pl experimental/data_viewer -am
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent
[INFO] common
[INFO] parent  <-- experimental folder one
[INFO] data_viewer
```